# Animate whole App with AngularJS, not talking about specific element

Tags: javascript, angularjs, architecture

I'm new to angularJs, trying to find the best way (the angular way) of animating my app, I've been reading about th ngAnimate (I understant the basic of how it works) but is not what I'm looking for, This is my base case:

I have the homepage (imagine the google landing page brand logo + google image + the input search and the button, white background). When I click search and get some results the DIV of the search moves itself to the upper righ, at the same time the background fades revealing a map that covers the whole page and shows some markers according to results. The results also are shown in a card like container (material design card UI like), another card appears if I click on each result (from result card or marker). If I change my search term then the previous cards dissapear. Some additional actions make some side columns to be revealed and change the disposition of the layout too.

My whole mess is that if I define a single Controller for each part of the app, some events in some parts changes the disposition of the other parts of the views related to the app, so I dont really know how to organize those cases and the animations related. Hope I made myself clear with the problem. The sad part is that all the tutorials and guides I've found are really specific and limited to animations of only one controller for any of the basic actions, show-hide ,add in repeaters, etc.

Thanks a lot.

maybe create a dedicated service to handle all the app animations with some state-machine with flags??.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We did not use a single controller for orchestration as @spanndemic suggested because all the overhead of the angular digest process was really high and it had a big impact on the UI, in terms of glitches. 
We tried two alternatives and somehow worked better, we choose the second that work the best.

1. First one was to work with an event model, at the required directives and controllers we subscribe to some specific events. We use the rootScope to publish this events so every controller can get the event when bubbled and each controller or directive could react to that event.
2. We based our app on states and used ui-router module. this had the best performance of all we tried, as we could define our UI depending on the current state, and it benefit of ui-router methods like stateChangeStart so we can detect before activating any animation on the page, even improve with plain javascript or CSS the animation process. With ui-router and stateChangeStart we could create and independent module just to control animations accros the app and no longer use animation code in the controllers that had to handle specific business code.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need a main controller that orchestrates communication between elements of the app, which in Angular would most likely be custom directives. Custom directives can then have their own controllers to execute animations on themselves.

Directive controllers can also incorporate other services/factories, which may help abstract some repeated animation code.

Directives:
https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive

Services:
https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services

Hope that helps!